# jQuery change event returns null when manually fired on $(document).ready();

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm currently writing a JQuery plugin that loads colors from a JSON web service into a drop down list.

The drop down list background-color changes according to the selected value.  For the most part it is working.  on any regular change it works as expected, the problem I am having is on the initial page load I am using `triggerHandler("change");` and it triggers but I seem to be getting an undefined error on the selected value from the drop down list on page load so it doesn't trigger the color change on the drop down list

My code is:

```
$.fn.bindColorsList = function (options) {

    var defColor = options.defaultColor;
    var svcUrl = options.svcurl;
    //var f_target = options.filterTarget;
    var $this = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: options.svcurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        /*data: { filter: src_filt },*/
        success: function (fonts) { fillcolors(fonts, $this) },
        error: function () { appendError(f_target, "colors failed to load from server") }


    });


    this.on("change", function (event) {
        log($(event.target).attr("id") + " change detected");

        //change ddl dropdown color to reflect selected item ;
        var hcolor = $this.find('option:selected').attr("name");


        $this.attr("style", "background-color:" + hcolor);


    });

function fillcolors(colors, target) {

    $(target).empty();
    $.each(colors, function (i, color) {
        $(target).append("<option name='"+color.HexValue+"' value='" + color.Name + "' style='background-color:"+color.HexValue+"'>"+color.Name+"</option>");
    });
};



//in a seperate file
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dd-font-color").bindColorsList({ svcurl: "/home/colors"});
        $("#dd-back-color").bindColorsList({ svcurl: "/home/colors" });




    });
```

Comment: Can you create a demo of your problem?

Comment: Use `$this` instead of `this` as they both point to same thing, no need to mix up, might create inconsistency along the selection.

Comment: http://chris-mcgrath.org/   has my current code

Comment: This is just a guess: Since `option` elements are not supposed to have `name` attributes and form elements are treated special at times, have you tried renaming the attribute to e.g. `data-name`? HTML5;'s `data-*` attributes are safe to use and you can also access the values with `$ele.data('name')`.

Comment: updated it to use the data-name attribute and changed it it to use $ele.data("name") still gives the same response   could it be its using the callback too early? should i use another event to delay the triggerHandler()?

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath, No somewhere we can edit the code too like jsfiddle.com

Comment: i can post the mvc project somewhere if you like

Comment: Ah, now I get it.... yes, it's probably because you call `trigger` before the Ajax call did not return. You could make your plugin accept a callback function which gets executed once the data is loaded, or trigger the change event inside the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an AJAX request to populate your dropdown which, by the way, is an asynchronous one. In this case you need to trigger the event in the `success` callback of the AJAX request.

```
var $this = this;

// Bind the onchange event
$this.on("change", function (event) {
  ..
});

// Populate using AJAX
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function (fonts) {
    // Populate the values
    fillcolors(fonts, $this);
    // Trigger the event
    $this.trigger("change");
  },
  ...
});
```

That's it.

Comment: think i tried that before but ill give it another shot and let you know how it goes

Comment: well ill be a monkeys uncle cant believe it was that simple =)

Comment: so is that each command i have defined in the success callback run synchronously ?  im new to jquery so im still not used to the idea of callbacks yet and when they are used

Comment: No. It depends on the functions you are calling actually. AJAX is asynchronous, unless you set it to be synchronous which is something you should not do. Other functions like setInterval and setTimeout has also asynchronous behavior.